# How to draw dotted circles using graphics in iPhone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-graphics

I am implementing a graphic based application. I am very new to graphics, I need to display a dotted circle in my view. Is it possible to draw a dotted circle using graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the method `-setLineDash:count:phase:` of the `UIBezierPath` class.